# SSL Certificate, Redirect, No-www done right (apache)?

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, 301-redirect, certbot

**MY GOAL**

I would like to make a website accessible only via SSL (encrypted) and with many domains redirecting to only one master domain (no duplicate content) and all www variants should be no-www.

The website is hosted by an apache server and configured as a virtual host.

I would like to have the redirections like follows:

`http://example.com -> https://example.com`

`http://www.example.com -> https://example.com`

`https://www.example.com -> https://example.com`

`http://example.de -> https://example.com`

`http://www.example.de -> https://example.com`

`https://example.de -> https://example.com`

`https://www.example.de -> https://example.com`

[...]

**THE ERROR / PROBLEM**

My problem is that certain requests (like `https://www.example.de`) are redirected to `https://example.com` but e.g. firefox says the connection is not secure (`SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`). Some others work.

My vhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com www.example.de example.de
  RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://example.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.de example.de
  RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://example.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  <Directory "/var/www/example">
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Example.com Temporary Preview"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/users
    Require user example-dev
  </Directory>

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using `certbot` for verfifying the domains and obtaining the ssl-certificate from letsencrypt like this:

`sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --installer apache certonly`

then selecting all the domains (which the apache installer guesses perfectly), specifying the webroot for the authentication process in the interactiv cli installer.

(Before the certbot process I use another vhost config for that domain, using only Port 80 to let the authentication process work)

**MY QUESTION / MISCONCEPTION**

I understand my apache vhost configuration like this:

- catch all **http** requests (all domains, with and without www) and redirect them to `https://example.com`
- catch all **https** requests (all domains except `example.com`, with and without www and redirect them to `https://example.com`
- finally catch **https** requests for `example.com` and serve the DocumentRoot with all the config as told in that third VirtualHost Block.

---

1. Why is the browser complaining in some cases, that the certificate is not valid for the given domain?
2. Is there a better/easier way to achieve what I want? Am I misunderstanding concepts of Apache-Redirections in that circumstance (SSL, no-www, letsencrypt)? Am I missing some part while using the `certbot` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you obtaining certificate for example.de? Even if you are doing a 301 redirect, browser first requests SSL for the domain which is redirected to another domain example: https://www.example.de is redirected to https://example.com.

So domain (https://www.example.de) must also have a valid SSL as it is requested first by browser. This would not be a case if you redirect non SSL http://www.example.de to https://example.com.

So make sure you issue SSL certificate for all SSL domains. Test those domains without redirection, and then implement your redirections.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that I requested ALL possible domains for the certificate. Also I thought about missing one, but it is really not working mainly when I request `httpS://` explicitly in the browser's address bar. So I guess, it might be a problem with my apache-vhost config. Like it is ignoring the second block or something??

Comment: BTW, i did not find a command on certbot's documentation that lists all domains for a certain certificate. Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: Thank you! By investigating further what you said, and my suspicion that there is something wrong with the second `VirtualHost`-Block in my config, it turned out that I had to add those three lines `Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem` to that second block also.